# ConcurrentModificationException using Collectors.toSet()

Tags: java-8, java-stream, concurrentmodification, jgrapht

I have a Set<Objects> that I want to filter by class to obtain a Set<Foo> (i.e., the subset of Objects that are `instanceof` Foo). To do this with Java-8 I wrote

```
Set<Foo> filtered = initialSet.parallelStream().filter(x -> (x instanceof Foo)).map(x -> (Foo) x).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

The problem is apparently the collector but I have no clue as to why.

Comment: Have you tried `initialSet.stream()` rather than  `initialSet.parallelStream()` ?

Comment: Parallel stream is not giving you anything here. Concurrency has an overhead.  Don't just throw it around because it sounds cool. A better rule of thumb: *never* use parallel stream unless you've actually established there is a bottleneck which a parallel stream will solve. I've worked with Java streams daily for the past 5 years, and I've needed to use parallel streams maybe once.

Comment: I've tried it both ways (i.e., stream and parallelStream) and had same results. I also broke it into separate parts:

 Stream<Object> stage1 = initialSet.stream();
  Stream<Object> stage2 = stage1.filter(x -> (x instanceof Foo));
but it had same results.

Comment: The exception indicates that the source collection has been modified while the operation was in progress. Since none of the operations you’ve shown does modify the source collection, the problem must be at the code you haven’t shown. It’s also very interesting that you say you have a `Set<Objects>`, presumably the `initialSet`, but the exception clearly stems from an operation processing an `ArrayList`…

Comment: @Holger: you're correct. The stream and collection code was a red herring. The issue turned out to be what was going on elsewhere (see my answer below)

Answer (score -1):

Found (and fixed) the problem. The issue is the `initialSet`. This is being obtained by a call to a 3rd party library (in this case a JGraphT `DirectedPseudoGraph` instance). The underlying graph was being modified on another thread. Since the `initialSet` is returned by reference the result is the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

The real problem is therefore not the stream processing but using a graph that returned a Set that wasn't thread-safe. The solution was to use `AsSynchronizedGraph`.

Comment: The original question does not show enough detail for anyone to understand this answer. The original question shows no code, and only mentions jgrapht in the tags.